# Android flash builder webview

Tags: android, flash, flash-builder

I'm currently developing a mobile application in flash builder for android.
In this application I’m using a web view, in this web view there is a link to a web-based application. The first thing you have to do is in this web-based application i login. This works fine. But i have one problem when i close the application and restart the application i always stay logged-in.

Is there any way to clear the data of a web view? Are options that clear the user data of the android application?

Here's my code

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;
        import flash.media.StageWebView;
        import flash.net.*;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;

        import spark.components.Application; 

        public var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 


        public function init():void 
        { 
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE , handleLoad );

        } 
        public function handleLoad(e:Event):void
        {

            webView.stage = this.stage;
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 50, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
            webView.loadURL("http://jd44jse.ncsbe.eu.jnj.com:54400/MfmWeb/flex/mfm/plocmenuHD/main.html");        
        }

        protected function logoutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();


        }




    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to add a code within the logout button that forces the user logout.  Or nullify the user information values upon exit. I am not at my computer but I will work on your code and see what I can discover.